# Format of applications submitted through Application Loader?

Tags: iphone, upload

When I am using Application Loader to upload the app binary to the Apple do I submit a .zip file of my whole application or the .ipa file. I am confused about this process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For iOS applications you just need to submit a zipped .app, the same .app generated by Xcode is enough, no need to put it into an IPA before archiving it.

For Mac OS X applications (Mac App Store), you need to submit the PKG generated by Xcode's Organizer Share/Save To Disk… command.

Alternatively, you can use the Build And Archive command and submit via the Xcode Organizer window… as another user points out.

Comment: Yes...When I do this I am receiving three errors:"Filename may not contain whitespace," "The signiture was invalid or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate," and "The bundle identifiers differ"

Answer (score 1):

If you have Xcode 3.2.5 then you can verify and upload your application through Organizer.

> 1.) Xcode -> Run -> **Build and Archive**
>
> 2.) Xcode -> Organizer -> Your Application *(under Archives)* -> **Verify / Submit**

Your app must already be setup and in `waiting for upload` mode in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create the archive in XCode 4, export as .ipa and upload that using Application Loader.

Answer (score 0):

You have to submit a .zip file containing your Release build (the .app file inside the `build/Release-iphoneos/` folder).

Answer (score 0):

There are several options.

One that worked for me is to use the Finder to find and select the .app bundle, then use the Finder menu item to Compress this .app bundle.  You can then select the resulting compressed file in the Application loader when your app is marked "Waiting for upload" in iTunes Connect.